# How to pass data from View controller to Container?

Tags: ios, swift, containers

I'm fairly new in using Swift Programming and need to pass some data to the Container view.

[image]

I have variables passed in to Eyewear Detail View Controller from another VC that I would like to then passed to the Container which is connected to a table.

In this, I have a dictionary of the information I like to put in the table.

I've been scratching my head to find an answer but to no luck on Google Search. Perhaps you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: your Embed segue is triggered immediately after the Eyewear view controller view loads so `prepareForSegue` is where you would normally share that with a view controller within a container view.

Comment: @Rog So, I should preprareForSegue in the Eyewear view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set segue identifier in storyboard, first of all. You could find the field where can set identifier after click segue link.

View Controller which will call next ViewController

```
func showSomeViewController() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TestContainer", sender: self);
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "TestContainer")
    {
        let vc: TestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TestViewController
        vc.tmpString = "say ho"
    }

}
```

and TestViewController

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

var tmpString: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}
```

Comment: I get it now.
Thanks everyone, your answers helped a lot and spared me countless hours of google searching!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` to pass the data.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[YourContainedViewController class]]) {
    // set data here
  }
}
```